# Having trouble tuning LSTM with an increasing val_loss issue

Tags: python, keras, lstm

Problem:

- Im looking to forecast the number of transcriptions for a particular user. I am using an LSTM to do so but as I fit the model, my training error continues to decrease but my validation error increases. I tried to handle for overfitting (see below) but that doesn't seem to be working.

**Summary:**

Training Samples: 409

Value Counts of response variable (transactions in next quarter):

- 0: 212
- 1: 125
- 2: 56
- 3: 13
- 4: 3

Training Set:

- Look back on the number of transcriptions over the last 4 weeks from time, t.

Here is the code:

```
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(5,  input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1,shuffle = False, verbose=2,validation_split = 0.10)
```

Any help would be much appreciated and please let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: Try the following combinations: `GRU(8, ..), GRU(10, ..)` each with `Dropout(0.1), Dropout(0.2)`. Or, remove `Dropout` and use `GRU(recurrent_dropout=0.2)`. With model this small, `Dropout` and strong regularization can _harm_ validation performance. Also, your dataset is very small - unsure the GRU can generalize effectively at all.

Comment: This stabilized the validation loss which is a great start! Any chance you can elaborate on why strong regularization can harm smaller models.